# Finding $k+1$ distinct points with integer difference in Lebesgue measurable set of measure $>k$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $k>0$ an integer such that $m(A)>k$ ($m$ is the Lebesgue measure). I would like to show that there exists $a_1, \dots, a_{k+1}$ such that for all $1\le i,j\le k+1$, $a_i-a_j\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I've managed to do it for the case $k=1$ as it is done in this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2968470/736429,
however I struggle to do it for $k>1$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

First, you may assume that $A$ is bounded, $A\subset [-M, M]$ for some $M$.

Now, consider for a natural $n$ the translates $A+k$, $k=1,\ldots, n$. Their union is included in $[-M, M+n]$ so it has measure at most $n+ 2M$. However, the sum of their measure is $n \cdot \mu(A)$. For $n$ large enough $n \cdot \mu(A) > k (n+2 M)$ ($\mu(A) > k + \frac{2 M}{n}$ for $n$ large). Now, if this happens then at least one point in the union has to be covered more than $k$ times.

---

Let's see why it will work. Initially we want $a_1$, $a_2$, $\ldots$, $a_{k+1}$ in $A$, distinct, such that $a_i-a_j$ are integers.  So let's say we find $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_{k+1}$ in $A$ and $m_1$, $\ldots$, $m_k$ natural, such that
$$a_i-a_j = m_j-m_i$$
for all $i$, $j$. Then we are OK.  Now, even if this problem seems a bit more involved, it simply means that

$$a_1 + m_1 = a_2 + m_2 = \ldots = a_{k+1} + m_{k+1} \ \  ( = b)$$

So the translates by different natural numbers $m_1$, $\ldots$, $m_{k+1}$ have a common point $b$.  If we can do that then we have the above and all is OK. Now, we only have to squeeze many translates in a fairly confined space and see that at some stages at least $(k+1)$ of them will have non-void intersection.

Comment: Thank you very much, very neat solution. I don't have much intuition on why it works though.

Comment: @Kieran McShane : a group of $N$ people was given $> k N$ dollars in total. Then at least one of them gets more than $k$ dollars.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that is also valid for $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Suppose $A\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ is a Lebesgue measurable such that $m(A)>M$ ($M\in\mathbb{N}$).
Partition $\mathbb{R}^n$ with cubes of the form $\mathbf{z}+(0,1]^d$, where $\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{Z}^d$.
$$A=\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}^d}A\cap(\mathbf{z}+(0,1]^d)$$
Define $A_{\mathbf{z}}:=A\cap(\mathbf{z}+(0,1]^d)-\mathbf{z}$ for each $\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{Z}^d$ and set $\phi=\sum_{\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{Z}^n}\mathbb{1}_{A_\mathbf{z}}$.
Clearly the  sets $A_\mathbf{z}$ are contained in $(0,1]^d$ and by translation invariance,
$$\int_{(0,1]^d}\phi=\sum_{\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{Z}^d}m(A_{\mathbf{z}})=\sum_{\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{Z}^d}m\big(A\cap(\mathbf{z}+(0,1]^d)\big)=m(A)>M.
$$
It follows that $m(\phi>M)>0$ (otherwise $\phi\leq M$ a.s. and so $\int \phi\leq M$, a contradiction!). Hence, there is $a\in(0,1]^d$ and $M+1$ distinct points $\mathbf{z}_j\in\mathbb{Z}^d$ such that $a\in\bigcap^{M+1}_{j=1}A_{\mathbf{z}_j}$. It follows that there're are $M+1$ points $x_j\in A\cap((0,1]^d+\mathbf{z})$, $j=1,\ldots,M+1$ such that
$a=x_j-\mathbf{z}_j$, $j=1,\ldots ,M+1$.
The points in $\{x_j:1\leq j\leq M+1\}$ are distinct (the sets $A_\mathbf{z}+\mathbf{z}$ are pairwise disjoint) and satisfy the desired condition.